# How to call sub function within export function in a Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have one function `getUsers` which I am deploying on my cloud function.

### index.js

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   // I want to call computeData function here
});

function computeData(user, x, algo) {

}
```

I do not want to export `computeData` function, just simply want to call it within export function. What is the way to do in Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call it like you normally would inside any other function:

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    computeData(...)
})
```